# How to fix responsive menu with css on wordpress + theme location

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I want build a menu responsive on wordpress with this codes:

```
<div id="main-nav">
<?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'main_nav', 
'class' => 'main-navigation ')); ?>
</div>
```

continue in (3 files, html, css and js): 
https://codepen.io/enbuilding/pen/XWrgwLb

please consider this:

1) Actually i only get a blank page

2) My location for the menu is main_nav on the wordpress admin panel (menu section)

3) im following this Tutorial: `https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-a-mobile-ready-responsive-wordpress-menu/` (option 3)

Comment: Have you installed the Responsive Menu Plugin? https://wordpress.org/plugins/responsive-menu/

Comment: hi, no, i want do the menu without plugins